# Cloned a table using Javascript; however some values no longer work after the cloning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, clone

I have a table called template and another which is a clone called attachments. I am having troubles getting an input field called `episodes_airdate` to display the same information supplied by using Javascript in the template table.

Here is the html for the template table:

```
<table id="template" style="display: none;" cellpadding="0px 20px" cellspacing="0px 20px">
    <tbody><tr class="line">
        <td width="100%">

        <p>
        <label>Season:</label>
              <select name="episode_season[]" select="" id="episode_season[]" class="season regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option></select>        </p>


        <label>Episode:</label>
        <p>
              <select name="episode_number[]" select="" id="episode_number[]" class="number regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option></select>        </p>

        <label>Title:</label>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="episode_title[]" id="episode_title[]" value="" class="title regular-text" style="width:400px;">
        </p>    


        <label>Airdate</label>
        <p>
                  <script>
        function datepopulate(){
    var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;
   var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
   document.getElementById('episode_airdate[]').value = completedate;
      alert(document.getElementById('episode_airdate[]').value);
   return true;
}

        </script>
    <select id="airdate_year" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">2012</option><option value="1910">1910</option><option value="1911">1911</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option></select><select id="airdate_month" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select><select name="airdate_day" id="airdate_day" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">10</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select> 
        <input type="hidden" name="episode_airdate[]" id="episode_airdate[]" class="airdate regular-text" value="--">

        </p>

         <p>
        <label>Plot:</label>
          <textarea name="episode_plot[]" id="episode_plot[]" class="plot regular-text" value="" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea>
        </p>
        </td>



        <td width="10%" class="commands">
            <a rel="delete" class="button">-</a> <a rel="add" class="button">+</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here is the html for the attachments table

```
<table id="attachments" style="border-spacing: 0px 30px;">

<tbody><tr class="line">
        <td width="100%">

        <p>
        <label>Season:</label>
              <select name="episode_season[]" select="" id="episode_season[]" class="season regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option></select>        </p>


        <label>Episode:</label>
        <p>
              <select name="episode_number[]" select="" id="episode_number[]" class="number regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option></select>        </p>

        <label>Title:</label>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="episode_title[]" id="episode_title[]" value="" class="title regular-text" style="width:400px;">
        </p>    


        <label>Airdate</label>
        <p>

    <select id="airdate_year" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">2012</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option></select><select id="airdate_month" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select><select name="airdate_day" id="airdate_day" onchange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;"><option value="">10</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select> 
        <input type="hidden" name="episode_airdate[]" id="episode_airdate[]" class="airdate regular-text" value="">

        </p>

         <p>
        <label>Plot:</label>
          <textarea name="episode_plot[]" id="episode_plot[]" class="plot regular-text" value="" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea>
        </p>
        </td>



        <td width="10%" class="commands">
             <a rel="add" class="button">+</a>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
```

This is the template table with a JavaScript adding 3 select options together called 
airdate_year , airdate_month , and airdate_day to make 1 value called episode_airdate witch is a hidden input.

```
<table id="template" style="display: none;" cellpadding="0px 20px" cellspacing="0px 20px">
    <tr class="line">
        <td width="100%">

        <p>
        <label><?php _e('Season:'); ?></label>
              <?php

                for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
                    $season_nums[]=$i;

                echo '<select name="episode_season[]" select id="episode_season[]" class="season regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                    echo '<option value="">' . __("0" ) . '</option>';
                    foreach($season_nums as $season_num){
                        $selected = '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $season_num . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $season_num . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select>';
                ?>
        </p>


        <label><?php _e('Episode:'); ?></label>
        <p>
              <?php

                for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
                    $episode_nums[]=$i;

                echo '<select name="episode_number[]" select id="episode_number[]" class="number regular-text" style="width:50px; float:left;">';
                    echo '<option value="">' . __("0" ) . '</option>';
                    foreach($episode_nums as $episode_num){
                        $selected = '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $episode_num . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $episode_num . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select>';
                ?>
        </p>

        <label><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
        <p>
          <input type="text" name="episode_title[]" id="episode_title[]" value="" class="title regular-text" style="width:400px;" />
        </p>    


        <label><?php _e('Airdate'); ?></label>
        <p>
                  <script>
        function datepopulate(){
    var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;
   var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
   document.getElementById('episode_airdate[]').value = completedate;
      alert(document.getElementById('episode_airdate[]').value);
   return true;
}

        </script>
    <?php

                for($i=1910; $i<=2012; $i++)
                    $years[]=$i;

                echo '<select id="airdate_year" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                    echo '<option value="">' . __("2012" ) . '</option>';
                    foreach($years as $year){
                        $selected = '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $year . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $year . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select>';


                for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
                    $months[]=$i;

                echo '<select id="airdate_month" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();" style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                    echo '<option value="">' . __("0" ) . '</option>';
                    foreach($months as $month){
                        $selected = '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $month . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $month . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select>';


                for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
                    $days[]=$i;

                echo '<select name="airdate_day" id="airdate_day" onChange="javascript:datepopulate();"  style="width:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px;">';
                    echo '<option value="">' . __("10" ) . '</option>';
                    foreach($days as $day){
                        $selected = '';
                        echo '<option value="' . $day . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $day . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select>';
                ?> 
        <input type="hidden" name="episode_airdate[]" id="episode_airdate[]"  class="airdate regular-text" value="">

        </p>

         <p>
        <label><?php _e('Plot:'); ?></label>
          <textarea name="episode_plot[]" id="episode_plot[]" class="plot regular-text"value="" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4" ><?php echo $_POST['episode_season'] ?></textarea>
        </p>
        </td>



        <td width="10%" class="commands">
            <a rel="delete" class="button">-</a> <a rel="add" class="button">+</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I created the table "attachments" to hold the cloned values of "template"

```
<table id="attachments" style="border-spacing: 0px 30px;">

</table>
```

Then this is the script I use to do the cloning and to show the results in the table "attachments". I think the problem may be with the script because if I use the template table it works fine; however after using this script with the cloning, the hidden input field "episode_airdate" returns blank. So i'm unsure what I need to modify between the function "datepopulate" and this below.

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    lines = 0;

    function items_init()
    {
        <?php $episodes = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'episodes', true) ?> 

        <?php if ( empty($episodes) ) : ?>                
        items_add();
        <?php else: ?>

        <?php 
        // Get serialized data
        $episodes = unserialize($episodes);

    // Compare episode numbers  
          function compare_number($a, $b) {
    if ($a['season'] == $b['season']) {
        return $b['number'] - $a['number'];    }

    return strnatcmp($b['season'], $a['season']);
  }

  // Sort by episode number 
  usort($episodes, 'compare_number');


        // Show episodes
        foreach ($episodes as $episode) :
         ?>
        items_add({
            title: '<?php echo base64_decode($episode['title']) ?>', 
            airdate:   '<?php echo $episode['airdate'] ?>',
            season:   '<?php echo $episode['season'] ?>',
            number:   '<?php echo $episode['number'] ?>',
            plot:   '<?php echo base64_decode($episode['plot']) ?>',

        });
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        // Delete the "-" button in first row
        $('#attachments tr:first-child .commands a[rel="delete"]').remove();
    }

    function items_add()
    {
        obj = $('#template tr').clone().appendTo('#attachments');
        lines++;

        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            options = arguments[0];
                var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;

            $('.title', obj).val( options.title );
            $('.airdate',   obj).val( options.airdate );
            $('.season',   obj).val( options.season );
            $('.number',   obj).val( options.number );
            $('.plot',   obj).val( options.plot );
        }
    }

    $('#attachments').delegate('.commands a', 'click', function()
    {
        var action = $(this).attr('rel');
        var confirm_delete = true;

        // Add action
        if ('add' == action) {
            items_add();
        }

        // Delete action
        if ('delete' == action) {
            // La TR en la tabla
            var oTr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var episode_name = $('.title', oTr).val();
            var episode_airdate = $('.airdate', oTr).val();
            var episode_season = $('.season', oTr).val();
            var episode_number  = $('.number', oTr).val();
            var episode_plot  = $('.plot', oTr).val();


            if (episode_name != '' || episode_number != '' || episode_plot != '') {
                if ( !confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + episode_name + '?') ) {
                    confirm_delete = false;
                }
            }

            if (confirm_delete) {
                oTr.next().remove(); oTr.remove();
                lines--;
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        items_init();
    });

})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: you need to clone the table 'template' with the same or you need to add some new stuff?

Comment: @JorgeOlivares The same, it just that it's not passing airdate_year, airdate_month, and airdate_day so i can save it in hidden input episode_airdate

Comment: What about.. if you do something like this whis jQuery? $('#attachments').html($('#template').html());

Comment: How you notice this behavior?

Comment: @JorgeOlivares I tried and it didn't work...was there any particular place I was supposed to paste it?

Comment: @Craig inside a $(document).ready(function () { ... });

Comment: @Prusse not sure what you mean? if you're asking how do i know it''s not added to episode_airdate, I placed an alert on the airdate_year , month, and day each time they are changed to show what the hidden input contains and it comes back blank or --

Comment: @JorgeOlivares just tried it; however no luck

Comment: `datepopulate()`? If yes you only believe it is not working. Since you got multiple items with the same id when you do `document.getElementById` it returns the first one it finds(ids should be unique, btw) and they are the ones from the template.

Comment: If you post the markup generated by the php will be easier to advice about a way to avoid using `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Prusse Yes datepopulate(). I see what you are saying but the ids are unique. If you are talking about duplicates then the ones from template should contain the values i'm looking for, shouldn't it?

Comment: Would you say this is more of a PHP file, or JavaScript, or HTML maybe? I never understood why people put markup in string literals in PHP in markup... why not just escape back into HTML? Anyway, I don't see how it's really possible to think about code like this clearly. It's a mess. As Prusse said, dealing with one aspect at a time (JS, or PHP, or whatever) would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do..

```
newObj = $('#something tr').clone(true, true);
// For cloning events and data, as well as deep copying
```

Answer (score 0):

`datepopulate()`? If yes you only believe it is not working. Since you got multiple items with the same id when you do document.getElementById it returns the first one it finds(ids should be unique, btw) and they are the ones from the template.

Try:

```
function datepopulate(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;
    var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
    $('episode_airdate[]', parent)[0].value = completedate;
    alert($('episode_airdate[]', parent)[0].value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: just tried it and no luck, it didn't return the alert message either.